# OSX 10.8 w/ OpenDirectory - Admin log in as user? and switch to Admin?

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, login, mac, opendirectory

I now have a OSX 10.8 workstation environment where the clients are bound to OpenDirectory on an OSX 10.6 Server and their home directories are stored on another OSX server.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to log into another user's account with administrative credentials?
   Say, I don't know the users password, and I need to fix something quickly before they arrive, and do not want to reset their password or change any account settings and say we don't have the password on file?
2. If a user is already logged in, but say, goes to lunch and doesn't come back, there monitor goes into power save mode, and then the next person to wake up the machine is presented with a login box with the username of the person who had left. Is there a shortcut key or something to be able to switch users or change to the admin user, or even better, to log back into the user's account by using admin credentials? At the log back in screen all that is presented is a Cancel button. I'm even unable to shut off the computer properly.

   - Ignoring auto log out settings, "require password ...after screensaver" settings, and password changes.

Before, with OSX 10.6 workstations, I was able to answer #2 because the software allowed whoever was sitting at the desk to modify the username field so I could safely save data and shut off the machine if the user, say, quit. I didn't have an answer for #1 though.

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible to login with admin credentials to another account, but you can connect an AFP share by providing original user name and admins password. This way you can test correct ACL setup on the shares.

You should use Workgroup Manager to change preferences/permissions for your users via MCX.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bob. I didn't think there was a way and I feel that is a bummer. I didn't know that about the AFP share.